# Screen Switching in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am a beginner in kivy and trying to use kivy screen manager to manage my screens.  I have a firstscreen with a button. click on a button will switch to the second screen which has custom label for the countdown of time.  When the time reaches 0 i try to switch to the thrird screen with some other widgets.  But the switch does not happen.  Can i know what am i missing?

My Code

```
class SecondScreen(Screen):


    number = NumericProperty(5)

    def getReady(self, value):
        self.number = value
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.increment_time, .1)
        self.increment_time(1)

    def increment_time(self, interval):
        self.number -= .1
        if round(self.number) == 0:
            self.stop()

    def stop(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.increment_time)
        sm.nextScreen()

    pass
```

(In ScreenManager class)

```
def readyScreen(self):       (Called from the firstScreen button)
    secondScreen = SecondScreen(name='ready')
    secondScreen.getReady(5)
    self.switch_to(secondScreen)


def nextScreen(self):
    thirdScreen = ThirdScreen(name='sets')
    self.add_widget(thirdScreen)
    self.switch_to(thirdScreen)
    print (self.current)
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No.  I do not get any error message.  It just hangs up in the second screen